# PHP if shorthand

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-operator

I have a string that I want to append it some other string. let's say:

```
$my_string = 'Hello';

$my_string .= ' there';
```

this would return 'Hello there'.

I want to make this conditional like this:

```
$my_string = 'Hello';

$append = 'do';

if ( $append == 'do' ) {

    $my_string .= ' there';

}
```

Now, I want to use a ternary operation to do this, but all the examples I came across are for if/else which will be something like:

```
$my_string .= ( $append == 'do' ) ? ' there' : '';
```

so is it possible to do it with only IF and without else?

Comment: can't you just concatenate a blank string for else?

Comment: Is it okay to just use an expression that is less complicated, e.g. not using the ternary operator, but just a logical one?

Comment: Try

if( condition ) return true;

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No... ternary means three parts   you need the condition, the true part, and the false part

Answer (score 28):

Nope. However, the opposite is possible. Here's a quote from the PHP docs:

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 21):

combining mellamokb and Andz you can do this:

```
( $append != 'do' ) ?: $my_string .= ' there';
```

Comment: +1 was going to say that, but couldn't properly test it on ideone :(  It does seem to be getting borderline unreadable and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: That's useless, it's the wrong operator. Use `OR` or `||`, but not `?`.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative way to check for a condition and then append to the string would be:

```
 ($append == 'do')  and  ($my_string .= ' there');
```

But that's really just an `if` displacement then. But comes close to an "ternary without the else".

Comment: @hakre: Had it originally without. But I noticed that's often better understood for explanation.

Comment: Yeah I was shortly irritated as I stumbled over them. However, it can make things easier to read, indeed. Like the whitespace which could be dropped as well but nobody would do, at least not overall.

Comment: Is there a technical name for this comparison?

Comment: its like `(exp is true) && ( executes_when_exp_is_true() );` camed from js

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
( $append == 'do' ) ? $my_string .= ' there' : $noop ;
```

If you invert the statement so that the ternary is on the outside instead of the inside of the assignment, then you can put an entire statement in the TRUE part, then just do something that is a no-operation command in the ELSE part.

Answer (score 4):

if you are considering to make the code shorter you can write the same thing on a single line.

```
if ($append == 'do') {$my_string .= ' there';}
```

**EDIT**

I just discovered this and thought come in handy. You can also write the if block like this

```
if ($append == 'do') $my_string .= ' there';
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use the ternary without the else/false part, but if your purpose is to have everything on one line I could suggest to try this alternative:

```
($append == 'do' && $my_string .= ' there');
```

If the first one is true it will proceed with the second statement. Otherwise will just stop after the first evaluation resulting false.

Refer to the lazy evaluation (the so called [Short-circuit evaluation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php))

Or you can do the opposite, leaving the *true* **if** part empty, and declare just the false, as Andz correctly points to.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that does what you want.  Instead of writing out the `if` statement each time.

```
function doAppend($doIt, &$value, $appendValue)
{
    if($doIt) $value .= $appendValue;
}
```

Call it with:

```
doAppend($append == 'do', $my_string, ' there');
```

Note how the second parameter is by reference, so it will be changed in the calling code too.

Answer (score 1):

a simple an very effective way could be to use `TRUE` `FALSE` values if you have nothing to return. Not only you have an argument but you can return with exact value you want to, like

```
$my_string .= ( $append == 'do' ) ? ' there' : true;
```